# Download all music in Apple Music library (iOS 10)

Tags: apple-music, ios

I just got a new phone on iOS 10 and I have an Apple Music subscription. I have the setting turned on to automatically download music when it is added, but all the existing music in my library hasn't downloaded. Is there a way to make it download everything, or do I have to do it manually album by album?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a perfect solution but it kinda works. On the Mac make a smart playlist that matches everything in your library.

[image]

Then on the iPhone, download that playlist for offline use.